# Create new columns based on rank order in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this,

```
ID  Hour    Prob       Rank
  
 123  10     0.4         4
 123  11     0.6         3
 123  12     1.0         1
 123  13     0.9         2
 456  10     0.8         1
 456  11     0.5         2
 456  12     0.1         4
 456  13     0.2         3
```

I am trying to create a data frame based on this which should like this,

```
  ID  Rank_1  Rank_2  Rank_3  Rank_4 Prob_1  Prob_2  Prob_3  Prob_4

  123   12      13      11      10     1.0     0.9     0.6     0.4
  456   10      11      13      12     0.8     0.5     0.2     0.1
```

I am not very familiar with pandas like tidyverse in R. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index(["ID", "Rank"])
df = df.unstack("Rank")
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda col: "_".join(map(str, col)))
```

where we first take `ID` and `Rank` to index side and then unstack the `Rank` to columns. Then joining the ranks with the column names `Hour` and `Prob` that were already there gives

```
     Hour_1  Hour_2  Hour_3  Hour_4  Prob_1  Prob_2  Prob_3  Prob_4
ID
123      12      13      11      10     1.0     0.9     0.6     0.4
456      10      11      13      12     0.8     0.5     0.2     0.1
```

but since you need `Rank` again instead of `Hour`, we lastly do:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("Hour", "Rank")
```

and get

```
>>> df

     Rank_1  Rank_2  Rank_3  Rank_4  Prob_1  Prob_2  Prob_3  Prob_4
ID
123      12      13      11      10     1.0     0.9     0.6     0.4
456      10      11      13      12     0.8     0.5     0.2     0.1
```

---

In case of duplicate entries in the `unstack` argument (i.e., `Rank` here), we can `append` whilst setting index. Then duplicate issue will be gone but a lot of `NaN`s would appear:

```
>>> df   # 2nd rows rank was made 4 for duplication

ID  Hour    Prob       Rank
  
 123  10     0.4         4
 123  11     0.6         4
 123  12     1.0         1
 123  13     0.9         2
 456  10     0.8         1
 456  11     0.5         2
 456  12     0.1         4
 456  13     0.2         3

# same operations, *except* `append=True`
>>> df = df.set_index(["ID", "Rank"], append=True)
>>> df = df.unstack("Rank")
>>> df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda col: "_".join(map(str, col)))
>>> df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("Hour", "Rank")
>>> df

       Rank_1  Rank_2  Rank_3  Rank_4  Prob_1  Prob_2  Prob_3  Prob_4
  ID
0 123     NaN     NaN     NaN    10.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.4
1 123     NaN     NaN     NaN    11.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.6
2 123    12.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
3 123     NaN    13.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.9     NaN     NaN
4 456    10.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.8     NaN     NaN     NaN
5 456     NaN    11.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.5     NaN     NaN
6 456     NaN     NaN     NaN    12.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.1
7 456     NaN     NaN    13.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.2     NaN
```

Now `pivot_table` can aggregate these; say we'd like to sum the values in duplications:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index="ID", aggfunc="sum")

     Prob_1  Prob_2  Prob_3  Prob_4  Rank_1  Rank_2  Rank_3  Rank_4
ID
123     1.0     0.9     0.0     1.0    12.0    13.0     0.0    21.0
456     0.8     0.5     0.2     0.1    10.0    11.0    13.0    12.0
```

Note that result is the same for the `ID`that didn't have any duplicates; for the other, it is 0 for rank 3 that didn't exist; and summation of values for rank 4.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this on my dataset which has hundreds of thousands of IDs' but received this error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". Would you please let me know how to handle this ? I am receiving that error in the second line of the code - df = df.unstack("Rank")

Comment: hi @Raju. That implies `Rank` column has duplicates per each ID. Is that desirable and how would you handle those in the output? E.g., if `ID` 123 has rank `3` two times.

Comment: @Raju Edited the answer for the case of duplicates, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you. I think I made a mistake in the previous step when creating ranks based on the Prob column. I see I have plenty of duplicates in Prob. I think I should handle it before this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `tidyverse` way in python with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, pivot_wider, rename_with
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.ID,  f.Hour,  f.Prob,  f.Rank,
...     123,   10,      0.4,     4,
...     123,   11,      0.6,     3,
...     123,   12,      1.0,     1,
...     123,   13,      0.9,     2,
...     456,   10,      0.8,     1,
...     456,   11,      0.5,     2,
...     456,   12,      0.1,     4,
...     456,   13,      0.2,     3,
... )
>>> 
>>> df >> pivot_wider(
...     names_from=f.Rank, 
...     values_from=[f.Hour, f.Prob], 
...     names_glue='{_value}_{Rank}'
... ) >> rename_with(
...     lambda col: col.replace('Hour', 'Rank')
... )
       ID  Rank_1  Rank_2  Rank_3  Rank_4    Prob_1    Prob_2    Prob_3    Prob_4
  <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64>
0     123      12      13      11      10       1.0       0.9       0.6       0.4
1     456      10      11      13      12       0.8       0.5       0.2       0.1
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.